# Ascending Sequence of Submodules

Tags: modules, homological-algebra

**Claim**: Consider an ascending sequence of submodules of a module $P$: $$\{0\} = P_0 \subseteq P_1 \subseteq P_2 \subseteq \cdots$$ where $P = \bigcup_{n \geq 0} P_n$. Suppose that $P_n$ is a direct summand of $P_{n + 1}$, that is $P_{n + 1} = P_n \oplus X_n$ for some submodule $X_n$ of $P$. It follows that $P = \oplus_{n \geq 0} X_n$.

**Thoughts**: I can show that $P_{n + 1} = \oplus_{k = 0}^n X_k$ just by induction on $n$. I can also show that $P = \langle X_n \rangle$ as I can pick $m \in P$, then $m \in P_{n + 1}$ for some $n$ and so $m \in \oplus_{k = 0}^n X_k \subseteq \langle X_n \rangle$.

I am unable to show that the elements can be written uniquely.

I've come across an argument for this, but I don't understand it:

> Suppose that $x_{n_1} + \cdots + x_{n_m} = 0$ is a shortest sequence with $x_{n_i} \in X_{n_i}$ and $n_1 < \cdots < n_m$. Then $-x_{n_m} \in X_{n_m} \cap X_{n_{m - 1}} = \{0\}$ (for the $X$'s are ascending), and this gives a shorter equation.

I can see that it's arriving at a contradiction, but I'm not sure what that contradiction implies (specifically how it's shown the uniqueness we want). Could it be that it's just showing that $0$ an be written uniquely and that's enough? Is it just telling us that the shortest equation just has one element which is equal to zero?

I also don't understand why $-x_{n_m} \in X_{n_{m - 1}}$ or why the $X$'s are ascending. As I understand it, the $X$'s all intersect at the zero module (even more than that) which is what tells us that $X_{n_m} \cap X_{n_{m - 1}} = \{0\}$ in the first place.

If someone could help me out with a good argument for showing the uniqueness property I need, or explain the argument I've mentioned in detail, I'd appreciate it.

**Source**: "Introduction to Homological Algebra", Joseph Rotman, 2nd Edition, p. 103. right before Propositon 3.8 (Kaplansky)

Comment: The $X$ are not disjoint (which would imply $X_{n_{m-1}}\cap X_{n_m}=\varnothing$), but their intersection is $\;\{0\}$.

Comment: My bad, you're right, I meant to say their intersection is $\{0\}$.

Comment: If they're an ascending  chain their intersection can't be reduced to $0$.

Comment: @Bernard, the $P$'s are an ascending chain. I don't think the $X$'s are even though that's what the book says. They should only have zero in common.

Comment: This remark: ‘for the $X$'s are ascending’ is plainly false, since the intersection of any pair of them is $0$.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. But then why is $-x_{n_m} \in X_{n_{m  - 1}}$?

Comment: He seems to use that  the $X$s are ascending, which for me is false. As I don't have the book, I can't see the context, which might explain.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is true but Rotman's approach needs tweaking.

Assume that we had such a shortest equation, and let $x_{n_m}$ be the element of largest index. Then $x_{n_m}\in X_{n_m}$, but $\sum_{i=1}^{m-1} x_{n_i}\in \oplus_{i=1}^{m-1} X_{n_i}\subseteq P_{n_{m-1}+1}$. We know that $P_{n_m+1}=X_{n_m}\oplus P_{n_m}$, and $P_{n_{m-1}+1}\subseteq P_{n_m}$ by the ascending condition. So $x_{n_m}\in P_{n_m}\oplus X_{n_m}=\{0\}$, so our equation wasn't the shortest.